# Как и откуда устанавливать сторонние библиотеки в Java, есть ли какой-то менеджер пакетов для этого языка?

Tags: java, модули

Я недавно начал учить Java. Я знаю основные конструкции языка и могу ими пользоваться.

Но мне интересно: как, где, откуда я могу устанавливать сторонние библиотеки.
Например, в Python есть pip, а пакеты хранятся в централизованном хранилище.
В JavaScript есть npm, все библиотеки скачиваются в папку node_modules.
Как же это происходит в Java, есть ли какой-то менеджер пакетов для этого языка?

Comment: Есть централизованное хранилище Maven и автоматизированный сборщик с одноименным названием (заодно и менеджер пакетов включен в него). Есть еще сборщик Gradle, тоже работает с хранилищем maven.

Answer (score 1):

Минимальный пример, как это сделать с помощью системы сборки [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org):

1. [Скачайте](https://gradle.org/releases/) Gradle последней версии с официального сайта и распакуйте архив.
2. Добавьте директорию [bin](https://gradle.org/install/#manually) в переменную PATH в вашей системе. Далее проверьте, что Gradle установлен с помощью команды:

   ```sh
   gradle --version
   ```
3. Создайте в вашем проекте три файла:

   Файл `settings.gradle`:

   ```
   rootProject.name = 'my-project'
   ```

   Файл `build.gradle`:

   ```
   plugins {
       id 'application'
   }

   group 'com.example'
   version '1.0'

   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
       implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0")
   }

   application {
       mainClass.set("com.example.Main")
   }
   ```

   Файл `src/main/java/com/example/Main.java`:

   ```java
   package com.example;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println("Hello Алексей!");
       }
   }
   ```
4. Запустите приложение с помощью команды:

   ```sh
   gradle run
   ```
5. Теперь вы можете добавлять любые зависимости в ваш проект. Добавляйте библиотеки в файл `build.gradle` в секцию `dependencies`. Для примера я добавил библиотеку [commons-lang3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0).

   На сайте https://mvnrepository.com/ вы можете найти любые другие библиотеки из Maven Central репозитория. Это основной репозиторий для Java-библиотек.

В своем примере я использовал плагин [`application`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html), чтобы иметь возможность запускать Main-класс из командной строки. Для более базовых вещей может быть достаточным подключить только плагин [`java`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) или плагин [`java-library`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html).

Answer (score -1):

Проще всего использовать не отдельно **Maven/Gradle** а **Spring** нужной сборки.

Переходишь на сайт - **https://start.spring.io/** и инициализируешь нужный пакет уже с какими-то зависимостями, данными и т.д, очень удобно, если хочешь быстро сделать пакет с *Spring Data, JDBC* и т.д например

**!Важно!**
*Ты в IDE должен распаковать проект и создать рабочую область*

Comment: даа, spring - это хорошо, но не новичку же...

Comment: Java, это же не только спринг... вопрос был в общем об управлении зависимостями.